# Angle between the minute hand and hour hand of a clock?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

At what time between $6$ a. m. and $7$ a. m. will the minute hand and hour hand of a clock make an angle closest to $60°$?

1. $ 6: 22$ a.m.
2. $6: 27$ a.m.
3. $ 6: 38$ a.m.
4. $ 6: 45$ a.m.

---

My attempt :

[The angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_angle_problem#Equation_for_the_angle_between_the_hands) between the hands can be found using the following formula:

\begin{align}
\Delta\theta
 &= \vert \theta_{\text{hr}} - \theta_{\text{min.}} \vert \\
 &= \vert 0.5^{\circ}\times(60\times H+M) -6^{\circ}\times M \vert \\
 &= \vert 0.5^{\circ}\times(60\times H+M) -0.5^{\circ}\times 12 \times M \vert \\
 &= \vert 0.5^{\circ}\times(60\times H -11 \times M) \vert \\
\end{align}
where

H is the hour
M is the minute
If the angle is greater than 180 degrees then subtract it from 360 degrees.

Therefore :

1. $59^{\circ}$
2. $31.5^{\circ}$
3. $29^{\circ}$
4. $67.5^{\circ}$

---

> Are my approach and solution correct ? Any other way to solve this ?

Comment: My solution is better. Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710765/the-angle-between-two-clock-pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : The hour hand moves $1/2$ degrees per minute while minute hand moves 6 degrees per minute. Hope this helps you.Thus it would be near to 60 at 6:22.so now here at 22 past 6 the hour hand would go 11 degrees while the minute hand would go 22.6=132 degrees so as per you stated it would be 180-132=48 so total angle would be 48+11 =59 nearest to 60.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.